# Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() returns no Value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

this is my first Stackoverflow Questions, so I'm trying to do my best to be clear and structured here but please forgive me for beginner mistakes :)

So I'm having a little issue with the Script Editor of Google, basically I'm calling the **Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()** as well as the **Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()** Function yet none of them is returning a value.

Here's the full Code I'm using:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var range = e.range;
    range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date() + "User is " + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() + "; " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Yet the Output I'm getting is always the same:
[Output in the Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSM4J.png)

The weird thing is, that this occured a few days ago, before that the same functions worked fine.

Has someone ever experienced something like this? Is there a workaround to get the Mail-Adress or the User-Name in the Script-Editor?

Comment: Is this a copy of a sheet is was working on previously?

Comment: Not quite, as it was originally implemented in a bigger Project. But it's basically the same function-call and the same issue.

Comment: So you have authorized the script in the new document?

Comment: To be honest, I think I did, but I'm not sure. I've added these oauthScopes Values in the appscript.json: [oauthScopes](https://image.ibb.co/ctx796/auth.png)

Comment: Update: I did authorize the Script but now I'm only getting the Console.log "Google Apps Script: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"

Trying later does not seem to work, as I'm getting this since yesterday :)

I do work with a workaround now nonetheless, but I'm still curious why it's not giving me the Mail-Adress anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In case you find yourself here] From the documentation:

> ...for example, the user's email address is **not available** in any
>   context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization,
>   like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger...

This explains the behaviour the OP was facing...