# Hiding worksheets from specific users inside a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Sorry I'm not familiar with coding, I have a spreadsheet with multiple worksheets, it's shared with many people, I'm trying to make those sheets  hidden by defaults when it's shared with a new person, and define some users as an admin users, and user groups for each location, I could run the code, and it worked when it was shorter, I know there might be easiest ways, however do you beilive there is a speific reason I'm getting nothing running the code, and users still see the hidden sheets unless I delete the IF statements.

Many thanks in advance.

```
function onOpen() {
      var Adminusr= ['amw22test.com','taaa@test.com','od22@test.com'];
      var Germanyusr = ['brs@test.com', 'ya32@test.com'];
      var Austriausr = ['dr32@test.com', 'ok42@test.com'];
      var Greeceusr = ['karw@test.com'];
      var Polandusr = ['shi0@test.com, Ma@test.com'];
      var Spainusr = ['sad2@test.com, ko12@test.com, tes4@test.com, kkwi@test.com']; 


        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Germany').hideSheet()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Austria').hideSheet()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Greece').hideSheet()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Poland').hideSheet()
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Spain').hideSheet()



      if (Adminusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0 || Germanyusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Germany').showSheet()
      }

      if  (Adminusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0 || Austriausr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Austria').showSheet()
        }

      if (Adminusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0 || Greeceusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Greece').showSheet()
      }

      if (Adminusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0 || Polandusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Poland').showSheet()
      }

      if (Adminusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0 || Spainusr.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Spain').showSheet()
      }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your project has two main problems

1. Authorization
2. Algorithm

---

## Authorization

You are missing the restrictions of `onOpen` and `Class Session`.

`onOpen` is a reserved name for the open simple trigger. When it's triggered by an open event, then can't execute methods that require authorization.

`Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` and `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` might work when the owner open the spreadsheet but will return an empty string when the spreadsheet is opened by an editor. Related question: [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() returns no Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48183463/1595451)

One trick to use a custom menu to save the active user email address on the User Properties store, then  `onOpen` could get the user email address from there instead of using `Class Session`. Related question: [Determine current user in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12300777/1595451)

## Algorithm

`onOpen` will be executed every time the owner or an editor, any editor, opens the spreadsheet no matter if another user is active, so if `brs@test.com` opens de the spreadsheet and few moments later `amw22test.com` do the same, the first user will see all the sheets.

Maybe instead of using one spreadsheet for all users you should create one spreadsheet for each group and one master spreadsheet for the admin group.

---

Other related questions

- [Google Spreadsheet - Show sheets depending on type of user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22368964/1595451)
- [Hiding tabs/sheets in Google Spreadsheet from certain users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50172217/1595451)
- [Determining Active Users on the same Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51336254/1595451)

Comment: Thank you Ruben, I will just go with your suggestion creating multi sheets. and trigger changes to be recorded to a master sheet for admins.